# How does ESRB content rating work for games with DLC?

Tags: content-rating, esrb

Lets say you have a game rated "Teen" by the ESRB, but later down the line, you release a DLC that would push the game's rating to "Mature". Are the two ratings kept separate for the base game and the DLC or will the base game be "upgraded" to the higher DLC rating?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two ratings are kept separate, and furthermore one only needs to resubmit the DLC if it would exceed the rating given to the base game, [as noted in the ESRB's rating guidelines.](https://www.esrb.org/ratings/ratings_process.aspx)